# Posting message to Facebook wall from web application

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, authorization

our web application posts messages to Facebook wall of logged user. We are using the Facebook Graph API. This feature did work in the past. When trying it today, I am getting an error message and cannot figure out where the problem is.

I am testing it with my Facebook account and I did not reject any permission.

When the user wants to connect his / her FB account with our web app, the app redirects to

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/?client_id=our_ID&redirect_uri=our_URI&state=generated_string&scope=email,publish_actions&response_type=code

Later, when the app calls

https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions?access_token=some_token

it receives response

```
{
    "data":[
        {
            "permission":"email",
            "status":"granted"
        },
        {
            "permission":"public_profile",
            "status":"granted"
        },
        {
            "permission":"installed",
            "status":"granted"
        }
    ]
}
```

The permission `publish_actions` is missing.

When the app POSTs to

https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token=some_token

with parameter

```
message=somemessage
```

the following error response is returned

```
{
    "error":
    {
        "message":"(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action",
        "type":"OAuthException",
        "code":200,
        "fbtrace_id":"FDM+n+5S14V"
    }
}
```

Why is the permission to post on wall suddenly not granted?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Users don’t have to grant your app the permissions it asks for, and they can remove permissions they previously granted at any time.

Comment: I have created a new Facebook user account. I have re-test this scenario. I have not rejected anything. I have still the same error.

Comment: How long “in the past” was it then, when this was working? Presumable before API v2, when Facebook introduced the review process? Then you need to submit your app for review and get the use of `publish_actions` approved by Facebook, before you can ask normal users for it. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/review

Comment: @CBroe It seems that you are right. The app has never been in the review process. Thanks.